# how fix Failed to open wav device LumiSoft.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, voice, lumisoft

i used this code for open wave device ,and get exception this "Failed to open wave device" .when i Reset computer it doesn't give exception and the first time i run the program it's OK,but after that each running ends with an exception .

```
public WaveOut(WavOutDevice outputDevice,int samplesPerSec,int bitsPerSample,int channels)
        {
            if(outputDevice == null){
                throw new ArgumentNullException("outputDevice");
            }
            if(samplesPerSec < 8000){
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument 'samplesPerSec' value must be >= 8000.");
            }
            if(bitsPerSample < 8){
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument 'bitsPerSample' value must be >= 8.");
            }
            if(channels < 1){
                throw new ArgumentException("Argument 'channels' value must be >= 1.");
            }

            m_pOutDevice    = outputDevice;
            m_SamplesPerSec = samplesPerSec;
            m_BitsPerSample = bitsPerSample;
            m_Channels      = channels;
            m_BlockSize     = m_Channels * (m_BitsPerSample / 8);
            m_pPlayItems    = new List<PlayItem>();

            // Try to open wav device.            
            WAVEFORMATEX format = new WAVEFORMATEX();
            format.wFormatTag      = WavFormat.PCM;
            format.nChannels       = (ushort)m_Channels;
            format.nSamplesPerSec  = (uint)samplesPerSec;                        
            format.nAvgBytesPerSec = (uint)(m_SamplesPerSec * m_Channels * (m_BitsPerSample / 8));
            format.nBlockAlign     = (ushort)m_BlockSize;
            format.wBitsPerSample  = (ushort)m_BitsPerSample;
            format.cbSize          = 0; 
            // We must delegate reference, otherwise GC will collect it.
            m_pWaveOutProc = new waveOutProc(this.OnWaveOutProc);
            int result = WavMethods.waveOutOpen(out m_pWavDevHandle,m_pOutDevice.Index,format,m_pWaveOutProc,0,WavConstants.CALLBACK_FUNCTION);



            if(result != MMSYSERR.NOERROR){
                throw new Exception("Failed to open wav device, error: " + result.ToString() + ".");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Altough I have little experience with wav devices in c#, I would think your problem is related to not closing the device when your program closes.

You need a call like

```
WavMethods.waveOutClose(m_pWavDevHandle);
```

somewhere before your application exits (it's obviously not needed if the waveOutoOpen call failed)